# MulticastSocket.setInterface in multi interface machine - how to use?

Tags: java, multicast

I have a machine with two network interface cards. I was wondering if I want to send out a multicast message to one of the LANs - is it mandatory to use the machine's ip in that LAN, or can have as input ant ip from the LAN?

That is, let's say the machine's IP is:
190.20.20.20
and another machine in that LAN is:
190.20.20.1

1. can I put:
   multcastiScoket.setInterface("190.20.20.1");
2. If so - does that machine have to be on turned on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC `MulticastSocket` is for *receiving* multicasted messages, and you need to configure it with `setGroup` to listen for multicast messages bound for a specific multicast IP address.
If you want to send a multicast message things are much simpler: you just send your message to that specific multicast IP address and the router/gateway will handle the actual multicasting logic for you. (So you do need to have a router/gateway which supports multicasting properly.)

EDIT: the Java tutorials cover this topic as well: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

Comment: You completley didn't understand the question.
I understand that I need to use a multicast IP, but multicast transimissions are by default restricted to the LAN they are sent on.

In case I have two interface cards, then I am connected by eacg to a different LAN. The way to control which LAN receives the multicast transimission is .setInterface.

Comment: @user967710 (1) Multicast transmissions aren't 'by default restricted to the LAN they are sent on'. 'LAN' isn't even a TCP/IP concept, let alone a default multicast scope. Multicasts are limited to whatever the intermediate routers permit, and there is no default for that. (2) setInterface() does not 'control which LAN receives the multicast transmission': it controls which *subnet* receives IGMP *join/leave group messages.*

Comment: @user967710 I am sorry, I did indeed misunderstand your question. From the way you phrased it I gathered you (a) didn't know how multicasting works because of point #2 ("does the machine need to be turned on") and (b) didn't know what the Java `MulticastSocket` is for (to me it looked like you wanted to use `MulticastSocket` to send specific messages to a group, rather than listen for them)...

Comment: @user268396 I don't see anything wrong with your answer. That *is* what he wants to do.

Answer (score 3):

While multicast has its own routing pecularities, it is important to understand that an explicit choice of the NIC (for both sender and receiver) is important and does make a difference (unless you want to rely on a particular OS'es "automagic" implementations, which can get very tricky in production).

Firstly, let us clarify, that `java.net.MulticastSocket` can and is used for both: sending and receiving messages (this does not mean that sending MC, and receiving MC are similar; a receiver must perform `IGMP` joins etc, is visible on `ip maddr` etc. etc.).

In general, the more you specify while creating these sockets the better (or else you will be at the mercy of the OS, with not-so-easy to debug situations bound to happen).

For the Receiver socket you should:

- specify the port (in constructor); firewall should be open for inbound `udp` traffic on that port,
- specify the interface (via `socket.setNetworkInterface`); else OS will take one of the available interfaces (check via `ip maddr`),
- specify the MC-group (e.g via `socket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName("230.0.0.0")`) (this triggers the IGMP mechanism, visible via `tcpdump -i your_interface -n ether multicast`)

For the Sender socket you should similarly,

- specify the MC group (same command),
- specify the interface (same command)

I'd put two arguments if favor of the above,

1. Tested simple senders and receivers on CentOS 7 with two NIC's (`enp0s3`, and `enp0s8`) [(code here)](https://github.com/pmarecki/mc/tree/master/src/main/java/multicast). Only by setting NIC expliclity on the receiver was I able to confidently tell on which NIC the IGMP join will be issued, and on which NIC the program will be listed (via `ip maddr`) as having joined the MC group; by setting the Sender onto specific NIC's it is readily verified, that a send on `enp0s3` will only reach a receiver on `enp0s3`, and not `enp0s8` (similarly, the `tcpdump` shows the packets as outbound on the chosen interfaces). This is so, of course, without starting to play with MC routing on the OS, which can be made to route the packets as wished for,
2. You may imagine a setup like yours, where two different NICs will lead to completely separated LAN's, which may further have all/complete elements of MC routing (designated routers, perhaps rendezvous points etc). Thus, selecting the proper NIC for IGMP joins is essential and determines *everything*; if these are issued to wrong NIC, you may not be able to receive MC traffic; if they are issued to both NICs, you may get more than you want.

I hope this helps (even if the question is 6 years old by now);

Answer (score 1):

The IP address in the setInterface() method is the address of one of your *own* interfaces. This is used in the case where you have multiple NICs, all connected to different subnets, and you want your multicast join and leave group messages to go out to a subnet that isn't the default route as per the IP routing tables.

In the case you mention there is no need to call setInterface() at all.

If you want a machine to receive messages it does have to be turned on.

Comment: I said: "I have a machine with two network interface cards", You said: "This is used in the case where you have multiple NICs... In the case you mention there is no need to call setInterface() at all".

Comment: @user967710 In the case you mention you are sending multicasts, not receiving them, and you aren't joining or leaving groups. You therefore don't need to call setInterface() at all, for the reasons I gave. You may need to *bind* your socket to one or other of your own NIC addresses, if the default IP routing won't get to 190.20.20.20 unaided. Your question about using the IP address of a third machine and whether it needs to be switched on is basically ridiculous.